# Error: illegal class main.java trying to access rect.java, how to fix this

Tags: java

I was making a project but a error popped when i run it says
'illegal class main.java trying to access rect.java'
Heres the code

```
package MyJavaProject;
import rect;
import box;
public class main{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  rect r = new box(100);
  r.getArea();
 }
}
```

rect.java

```
package JavaProject;
public class box extends rect{
 private int size;
 public rect(size){
  super(size,size);
 }
}
public class rect{
 private int height,width;
 public rect(height,width){
  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;
 }
 public int getArea(){
  System.out.println(height * width);
  return 0;
 }
}
```

Can you please fix it?

I was expecting output:
'10000'
But it came:
error illegal class main.java trying to access rect.java
If anybody knows how to fix it then give me the answer.

Comment: Your import statement has to include the package name. Also, please confirm to Java naming conventions.

Comment: You don't `import classname` you `import pkgpath.classname`. So `import JavaProject.rect;` But you need to get those names in the correct [format](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)

Comment: Your classes are in different packages (`MyJavaProject` != `JavaProject`). Was that intentional?

Comment: @g00se Thanks now i understand how to do it :D

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Don't need now :l

Comment: I'd *strongly* advise you to start following Java naming conventions as soon as possible. It's much easier to get into the right habit from the start than to "unlearn" a bad habit.

Comment: If your classes are in the same package (have the same package name), you don’t need to import them at all. Import is for accessing classes and interfaces in *other* packages.